# React / single page / struct header/content/footer

Tags: css, reactjs, react-router

Hello so far I have this:

app js:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
  <BrowserRouter>
  <PublicRoute restricted={false} component={Header} path={['/']} exact />
  <Switch>
    <PublicRoute restricted={false} component={Content} path="/" exact />
    <PublicRoute restricted={false} component={Content2} path="/" exact />
  </Switch>
  <PublicRoute restricted={false} component={Footer} path={['/']} exact />
  </BrowserRouter>
  )
}
header.js

const Header = () => {
    return(
    <div style={{backgroundColor:'#000'}}>
        Header
    </div>
    )  
}
```

footer.js

```
import React from 'react';

const Footer = () => {
    return(
    <div style={{backgroundColor:'#eee'}}>
        Footer
    </div>
    )
}
```

I don't know if I'm on the right track about a single page but I'm having a hard time finding the best solution for placing my footer sickey at bottom 0

Comment: what is "footer sickey" ?

Comment: fixed and stickey to the bottom of the browser window

Comment: I think that is a CSS problem. Try: `#footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}`

Comment: Yes I did cs too, but I also asked about routes, single page

but how would i put my content?

Comment: go to: `https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start` and follow the samples. It will get you up and running quickly with your routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You have 2 ways to create such a site

> 1)that you use:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
         <>
       <BrowserRouter>

    <YourHeaderComponent/>
            <Switch>
            {yourRoutesArray.map (route => (
               <Route
                key={route.path}
                path={route.path}
                exact={route.exact}
                component={route.component}
                />
              ))}
          <Route component={Your404Component} />
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>

    <YourFooterComponent/>
    </>
    )}
```

> 2)that you use with layout:

```
export const withLayout = (Page: any) => {
 return (
   <>
        <Header />
        <Page {...props} />
        <Footer />
   </>
      );
}
```

and in all of your roots export it like this

```
const YourComponent =()=>{
   return(
       <div>hello</div>
   )
}

export default withLayout(YourComponent);
```

Comment: Thank you
which one do you think is better?

thank you !!

Comment: I've used both ways but i think the 2nd way is more stable because it's not dependent on a library.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
const App = () => {
    return (
    <BrowserRouter>
    <Header />
    <Switch>
      <Route restricted={false}  path="/" exact><Content /></Route> 
      <Route restricted={false}  path="/contenttwo" exact /><ContentTwo /></Route>
    </Switch>
    <Footer />
    </BrowserRouter>
    )
  }
```

This will always render your header and footer component and only change the content based on routes.